# php websocket looses user's data only sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket

I'm new to websockets and I'm facing a problem that I can't manage to fix. I've downloaded server and client from the web and modified it to have it working my way. The problem is I want to store users' data(e.g. name,color, whatever) on the serverside. When I want to spread the message from one user to all other users it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't. Funny thing is that it reads user's id perfectly every time but sometimes it looses name or color, which all are, in fact, the fields of the same class and I don't see the difference... Please help.

Server:

```
        <?php
    /**
    * Simple server class which manage WebSocket protocols
    * @author Sann-Remy Chea <http://srchea.com>
    * @license This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.
    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.
    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
    * @version 0.1
    */
    class Server {

    /**
    * The address of the server
    * @var String
    */
    private $address;

    /**
    * The port for the master socket
    * @var int
    */
    private $port;

    /**
    * The master socket
    * @var Resource
    */
    private $master;

    /**
    * The array of sockets (1 socket = 1 client)
    * @var Array of resource
    */
    private $sockets;

    /**
    * The array of connected clients
    * @var Array of clients
    */
    private $clients;

    /**
    * If true, the server will print messages to the terminal
    * @var Boolean
    */
    private $verboseMode;

    private $maxConnections = 3;

    /**
    * Server constructor
    * @param $address The address IP or hostname of the server (default: 127.0.0.1).
    * @param $port The port for the master socket (default: 5001)
    */
    function Server($address = '127.0.0.1', $port = 5001, $verboseMode = false) {
    $this->console("Server starting...");
    $this->address = $address;
    $this->port = $port;
    $this->verboseMode = $verboseMode;

    // socket creation
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

    if (!is_resource($socket))
    $this->console("socket_create() failed: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error()), true);

    if (!socket_bind($socket, $this->address, $this->port))
    $this->console("socket_bind() failed: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error()), true);

    if(!socket_listen($socket, 20))
    $this->console("socket_listen() failed: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error()), true);
    $this->master = $socket;
    $this->sockets = array($socket);
    $this->console("Server started on {$this->address}:{$this->port}");
    }

    /**
    * Create a client object with its associated socket
    * @param $socket
    */
    private function connect($socket) {
    $this->console("Creating client...");
    $client = new Client(uniqid(), $socket);
    $this->clients[] = $client;
    $this->sockets[] = $socket;
    $this->console("Client #{$client->getId()} is successfully created!");
    }

    /**
    * Do the handshaking between client and server
    * @param $client
    * @param $headers
    */
    private function handshake($client, $headers) {
    $this->console("Getting client WebSocket version...");
    if(preg_match("/Sec-WebSocket-Version: (.*)\r\n/", $headers, $match))
    $version = $match[1];
    else {
    $this->console("The client doesn't support WebSocket");
    return false;
    }

    $this->console("Client WebSocket version is {$version}, (required: 13)");
    if($version == 13) {
    // Extract header variables
    $this->console("Getting headers...");
    if(preg_match("/GET (.*) HTTP/", $headers, $match))
    $root = $match[1];
    if(preg_match("/Host: (.*)\r\n/", $headers, $match))
    $host = $match[1];
    if(preg_match("/Origin: (.*)\r\n/", $headers, $match))
    $origin = $match[1];
    if(preg_match("/Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n/", $headers, $match))
    $key = $match[1];

    $this->console("Client headers are:");
    $this->console("\t- Root: ".$root);
    $this->console("\t- Host: ".$host);
    $this->console("\t- Origin: ".$origin);
    $this->console("\t- Sec-WebSocket-Key: ".$key);

    $this->console("Generating Sec-WebSocket-Accept key...");
    $acceptKey = $key.'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11';
    $acceptKey = base64_encode(sha1($acceptKey, true));

    $upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n".
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $acceptKey".
    "\r\n\r\n";

    $this->console("Sending this response to the client #{$client->getId()}:\r\n".$upgrade);
    socket_write($client->getSocket(), $upgrade);
    $client->setHandshake(true);
    $this->console("Handshake is successfully done!");
    return true;
    }
    else {
    $this->console("WebSocket version 13 required (the client supports version {$version})");
    return false;
    }
    }

    /**
    * Disconnect a client and close the connection
    * @param $socket
    */
    private function disconnect($client)
    {
        $this->console("Disconnecting client #{$client->getId()}");
        $i = array_search($client, $this->clients);
        $j = array_search($client->getSocket(), $this->sockets);

        if($j >= 0)
        {
            array_splice($this->sockets, $j, 1);
            socket_shutdown($client->getSocket(), 2);
            socket_close($client->getSocket());
            $this->console("Socket closed");
        }

        if($i >= 0)
        array_splice($this->clients, $i, 1);
        $this->console("Client #{$client->getId()} disconnected");
        /*foreach ($this->clients as $cnt)
            $this->send($cnt,$this->usernames[$client->getId()] ." left!");*/
    }

    /**
    * Get the client associated with the socket
    * @param $socket
    * @return A client object if found, if not false
    */
    private function getClientBySocket($socket) {
    foreach($this->clients as $client)
    if($client->getSocket() == $socket) {
    $this->console("Client found");
    return $client;
    }
    return false;
    }

    /**
    * Do an action
    * @param $client
    * @param $action
    */
    private function action($client, $action)
    {
        $action = $this->unmask($action);
        $this->console("Performing action: ".$action);
        if($action == "exit" || $action == "quit")
        {
            $this->console("Killing a child process");
            posix_kill($client->getPid(), SIGTERM);
            $this->console("Process {$client->getPid()} is killed!");
        }
    }

    /**
    * Run the server
    */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->console("Start running...");
        while(true)
        {
            $changed_sockets = $this->sockets;
            @socket_select($changed_sockets, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 1);
            foreach($changed_sockets as $socket)
            {
                if($socket == $this->master)
                {
                    if(($acceptedSocket = socket_accept($this->master)) < 0)
                    {
                        $this->console("Socket error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($acceptedSocket)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->connect($acceptedSocket);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->console("Finding the socket that associated to the client...");
                    $client = $this->getClientBySocket($socket);
                    if($client)
                    {
                        $this->console("Receiving data from the client");

                        $data=null;
                        while($bytes = @socket_recv($socket, $r_data, 2048, MSG_DONTWAIT))
                        {
                            $data.=$r_data;
                        }

                        if(!$client->getHandshake())
                        {
                            $this->console("Doing the handshake");
                            if($this->handshake($client, $data))
                            $this->startProcess($client);
                        }
                        elseif($bytes === 0)
                        {
                            $this->console("disconnecting...");
                            $this->disconnect($client);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $data = (string)$this->unmask($data);
                            $data = json_decode($data);
                            if( $data != "" )$this->console("Got data from user: |" . implode(',',$data) . "|");
                            // When received data from client
                            if( $data[0] == "setName" )//set name, color for user with given id
                            {
                                $id = $client->getId();
                                $colors = array( '990099','660099','66ccff','339933','99ff00','ccff00','663300','cc0000' );
                                //$col = '#'.$colors[ rand(0, sizeof($colors)-1) ];
                                $col = '#'.$colors[ sizeof( $this->clients ) ];
                                $this->console( "Setting attributes for user $id | ". $data[1] ." | $col |" );
                                $client->setName( $data[1] );
                                $client->setColor( $col );
                            }
                            else if( $data != "" )
                            {
                                $counter = 0 ;
                                $id = $client->getId();
                                $name = null ;
                                $color = null ;
                                //while($name == null)
                                if(1)
                                {
                                    foreach ($this->clients as $c)
                                    {
                                        if( $c->getId() == $id )
                                        {
                                            $name = $c->getName();
                                            $color = $c->getColor();
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ++$counter;
                                }
                                foreach ($this->clients as $c)
                                {
                                    $this->send( $c, json_encode( array( 
                                                                        $name . "[$counter]", 
                                                                        $color, 
                                                                        $data[1] )
                                                                ) );
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /**
    * Start a child process for pushing data
    * @param unknown_type $client
    */
    private function startProcess($client)
    {
        $this->console("Start a client process");
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if($pid == -1)
        {
            die('could not fork');
        }
        elseif($pid)
        { // process
            $client->setPid($pid);
        }
        else
        {
            if( sizeof( $this->clients ) > $this->maxConnections )
            {
                $this->send( $client, json_encode(array("No free slots!")) );
                $this->disconnect($client);
            }
            else
                $this->send($client, json_encode($client->getId()));
            // we are the child
            while(false)
            {

                //if the client is broken, exit the child process
                if($client->exists==false)
                {
                    break;
                }   

                // push something to the client
                $seconds = rand(2, 5);
                $this->send($client, "I am waiting {$seconds} seconds");
                sleep($seconds);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Send a text to client
    * @param $client
    * @param $text
    */
    private function send($client, $text) {
        $this->console("Send '".$text."' to client #{$client->getId()}");
        $text = $this->encode($text);
        if( socket_write($client->getSocket(), $text, strlen($text)) === FALSE )
        {
            $client->exists=false; //flag the client as broken
            $this->console("Unable to write to client #{$client->getId()}'s socket");
            $this->disconnect($client);
        }
        else
            $this->console ("data sent!");
    }

    /**
    * Encode a text for sending to clients via ws://
    * @param $text
    * @param $messageType
    */
    function encode($message, $messageType='text') {

    switch ($messageType) {
    case 'continuous':
    $b1 = 0;
    break;
    case 'text':
    $b1 = 1;
    break;
    case 'binary':
    $b1 = 2;
    break;
    case 'close':
    $b1 = 8;
    break;
    case 'ping':
    $b1 = 9;
    break;
    case 'pong':
    $b1 = 10;
    break;
    }

    $b1 += 128;


    $length = strlen($message);
    $lengthField = "";

    if ($length < 126) {
    $b2 = $length;
    } elseif ($length <= 65536) {
    $b2 = 126;
    $hexLength = dechex($length);
    //$this->stdout("Hex Length: $hexLength");
    if (strlen($hexLength)%2 == 1) {
    $hexLength = '0' . $hexLength;
    }

    $n = strlen($hexLength) - 2;

    for ($i = $n; $i >= 0; $i=$i-2) {
    $lengthField = chr(hexdec(substr($hexLength, $i, 2))) . $lengthField;
    }

    while (strlen($lengthField) < 2) {
    $lengthField = chr(0) . $lengthField;
    }

    } else {

    $b2 = 127;
    $hexLength = dechex($length);

    if (strlen($hexLength)%2 == 1) {
    $hexLength = '0' . $hexLength;
    }

    $n = strlen($hexLength) - 2;

    for ($i = $n; $i >= 0; $i=$i-2) {
    $lengthField = chr(hexdec(substr($hexLength, $i, 2))) . $lengthField;
    }

    while (strlen($lengthField) < 8) {
    $lengthField = chr(0) . $lengthField;
    }
    }

    return chr($b1) . chr($b2) . $lengthField . $message;
    }


    /**
    * Unmask a received payload
    * @param $buffer
    */
    private function unmask($payload) {
    $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;

    if($length == 126) {
    $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
    $data = substr($payload, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
    $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
    $data = substr($payload, 14);
    }
    else {
    $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
    $data = substr($payload, 6);
    }

    $text = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
    $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
    }

    /**
    * Print a text to the terminal
    * @param $text the text to display
    * @param $exit if true, the process will exit
    */
    private function console($text, $exit = false) {
    $text = date('[Y-m-d H:i:s] ').$text."\r\n";
    if($exit)
    die($text);
    if($this->verboseMode)
    echo $text;
    }
    }

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once 'client.php';

    set_time_limit(0);

    // variables
    $address = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = 5001;
    $verboseMode = true;

    $server = new Server($address, $port, $verboseMode);
    $server->run();


    ?>
```

Client:

```
        <?php
    /**
    * Define a Client object
    * @author Sann-Remy Chea <http://srchea.com>
    * @license This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.
    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.
    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
    * @version 0.1
    */
    class Client {
    private $id;
    private $socket;
    private $handshake;
    private $pid;

    private $name;
    private $color;

    public $exists=true; //to check if client is broken



    function Client($id, $socket) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->socket = $socket;
    $this->handshake = false;
    $this->pid = null;
    }

    public function setName( $n )
    {
        $this->name = $n;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setColor( $c )
    {
        $this->color = $c;
    }

    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }

    public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSocket() {
    return $this->socket;
    }

    public function getHandshake() {
    return $this->handshake;
    }

    public function getPid() {
    return $this->pid;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setSocket($socket) {
    $this->socket = $socket;
    }

    public function setHandshake($handshake) {
    $this->handshake = $handshake;
    }

    public function setPid($pid) {
    $this->pid = $pid;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Index:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pl">
    <head>
            <title>Websockets</title>

            <meta name="BB" content="" />
            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta name="keywords" content="" />
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />

            <style>

                html, body
                {
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;

                }

                #out
                {
                    width:840px;
                    height:500px;
                    mragin-right: -20px;
                    color:#FFF;
                    font-family: Courier New;
                    overflow-x: hidden;
                    overflow-y: auto;
                }

                #outwrap
                {
                    width:800px;
                    height:500px;
                    margin:40px auto 0 auto;
                    display: block;
                    border: 1px solid #F00;
                    background-color: #000;
                    padding: 10px;
                    overflow:hidden;
                }

                #field
                {
                    width:820px;
                    margin:10px auto;
                    display: block;
                    background-color: #000;
                    color: #FFF;
                    height: 50px;
                }

                #btn
                {
                    background-color: #000;
                    margin:0 auto;
                    display:block;
                    width:100px;
                    height:50px;
                    font-size:20px;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                }

                #btn:hover
                {
                    background-color: #666;
                }

            </style>

            <script>

                "use strict";

                function $(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

                    var name = "";
                    while( name === "" || name === null )name = window.prompt( "Name" );

                    var myId = '';
                    $("field").value = "";
                    $("field").focus();

                    //var colors = ['990099','660099','66ccff','339933','99ff00','ccff00','663300','cc0000'];
                    //var myColor = '#' + colors[Math.floor( Math.random()*colors.length )] ;

                    //$("btn").style.color = myColor ;


                    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:5001');

                    ws.onopen = function(msg) {

                        write( "connected as "+ name +"!" );
                        ws.send( JSON.stringify( new Array( "setName",name ) ) );
                        $("field").focus();
                        //ws.send( name+": connected" );
                        //write('Connection successfully opened (readyState ' + this.readyState+')');
                    };
                    ws.onclose = function(msg) {
                        if(this.readyState === 2)write( "disconnected!" );
                            /*write(
                                'Closing... The connection is going throught'
                                + 'the closing handshake (readyState '+this.readyState+')'
                            );*/
                        else if(this.readyState === 3)write( "disconnected!" );
                            /*write(
                                'Connection closed... The connection has been closed'
                                + 'or could not be opened (readyState '+this.readyState+')'
                            );*/
                        else write( "disconnected!" );
                            //write('Connection closed... (unhandled readyState '+this.readyState+')');
                    };
                    ws.onerror = function(event) {
                        if(typeof (event.data) != 'undefined')write( "ERROR:" + event.data );
                    };

                    ws.onmessage = function(e){

                        var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
                        msg = msg.toString().split(",");
                        if( msg.length == 1 )myId = msg.toString();
                        else
                        {
                            write( "<p style='color:"+ msg[1] +";'>"+ msg[0] +": "+ msg[2] +"</p>" );
                        }
                        console.log( "Server -> " + msg );

                        //write( "inc: " + msg );
                    };

                    $("field").addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
                        if( e.keyCode == 13 )
                        {
                            $("btn").click();
                        }
                    });

                    $("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){

                        if( ws.readyState === 1 )
                            ws.send( JSON.stringify( new Array( myId, $("field").value ) ) );
                        else write( "Couldn't send the message..." );

                        $("field").value = "";
                        $("field").focus();

                    });

                    window.onbeforeunload = function()
                    {
                        //ws.send( name+": disconnected" );
                        ws.close();
                    }

                    function write( info )
                    {
                        //$("out").innerHTML = info + "<br />" + $("out").innerHTML;
                        var p = document.createElement( "p" );
                        p.innerHTML = info ;
                        $("out").appendChild( p );
                        $("out").scrollTop = $("out").scrollHeight;
                    }

                });


            </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="outwrap">
            <div id="out"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="field" />
        <input type="button" value="SEND" id="btn" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

If you uncomment while on line 278(server.php) and comment if a line below: In case about which I'm talking about the loop goes infinite...

Answer (score 0):

You are making the common (beginners?) mistake to assume that writing/reading to/from a TCP socket does send/receive the amount of bytes the calls were told to send/receive. This is **not** necessarily the case.

It is essential to inspect the value those functions (`socket_recv()`/`socket_send()`) return and loop around them until all data had been sent/received.

Comment: What do you mean? That the script haven't receive all those bytes yet and I'm trying to send response to client or what?

Comment: @user3741410: Compare the value returned by the seperate calls to `socket_read()` and `socket_write()` to the amount of bytes they should have been written/read and you'll see what I mean. Also reading the related documentation might help to understand the issue my answer referrs to.

Comment: I don't seem to fully understand this yet, could you pass me some well written tutorial talking about it? I've been reading many tuts through the web btw.

Comment: If you tell `socket_write/socket_send` to write/send N bytes it might very well only write/send N - M = K bytes. This will be inidicated by `socket_write/socket_send` returning M. Same for `socket_recv()`. For `socket_read()` one needs to check the length of the string returned to see whether its length matches what was expected. Also P calls to `socket_send()` could result in Q necessary calls to `socket_recv()` to get the data on the other side. TCP is stream oriented not message oriented.

Comment: Correction to my first comment: `socket_read()` should have been `socket_recv()`. @user3741410

Comment: Thank You very much! :) I got it, now there's an issue to code it correctly. Wish me luck, peace ;)

Comment: Correction to me 2nd comment: "*... returning M.*" should read "*... returning K.*".

Comment: One more thing. I've done some tests and it turned out that the server receives correct id but can't manage to load name an color of the user with that id. It doesn't seem to be problem with transferring data. It looks really weird, try to launch my code and watch the console. Still not working.